# Morphia Upserting Field as int64 instead of in32

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I've written an operation upsert a document to Mongo using Morphia.

I have a field which I want to save as an int32, but after the upsert it is inserted as int64.

I have made sure that I convert the long as an int using Long.intValue() and the object that Morphia serializes back to, the member field is int. I have also checked the UpdateOperations.ops to see what morphia is upserting.

The upsert operation is:

```
UpdateOperations<Test> ops = datastore.createUpdateOperations(Test.class)
  .set("test_field", testField.intValue())
```

The current version of Mongo I am using is 3.0.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:
Looking at the update query operation in Morphia it is:

```
{$set={test_field=11}}
```

Comment: Can you add a complete example ? How are you verifying it is Int64 in database ? Can you execute  `db.collection_name.find( { "test_field" : { $type : 18 } } )`  in shell ?;

Comment: `db.collection_name.find( { "test_field" : { $type : 18 } } )` returns me the only document I have in my collection. I am also using Robomongo which confirms the type of each field within a document.
I have dropped the collection to make sure no indexes are holding onto values

Comment: Also, I have checked to JSON for the document, the field has "test_field": NumberLong(1)

Comment: No, I cant reproduce it on my end on morphia 1.3.0 version on Mongo 3.2. Could you provide a complete example which includes `Test` pojo ,  `upsert` code  and sample document from your collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the solution. The query for the upsert was querying on the test_field as a long rather than an int. Mongo 3.0 sees this as the type to insert - however running on Mongo 3.2, there is no issue and it will upsert with the type specified in the upsert operation, not the query.